# UbuntuStudio lost my passeword ! what to do please

Tags: software-installation

Any Ideas I run on ubuntustudio live for now. new and lost lol

Comment: You forgot your password - it happens -, not the OS. As long as you have backups just reinstall and don't forget about the user's password. If you don't have backups then consider the files lost because even after forcing a new password you won't have access to those files. That's what passwords are for.

Comment: If your Ubuntu Studio was installed with encrypted disk, there is no way to get into it without a password :-( Otherwise there is a way to create a new password :-)